# Python: Combining NOT, AND, IN in one IF statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically I need to check if var is an alphabetic character in ASCII.
So r_upper is the range of upper characters.
r_lower is the range of lower characters.
and 32 is the value for space. (Later .strip() will be implemented)

I've never done something like this, so probably the error is very visible, or this may not be possible ?

```
r_upper = range(65, 91)
r_lower = range(97, 123)
var = 95
if var not in r_lower or var not in r_upper or var !== 32:
    print("Worked")
```

I also tried:

```
if not var in r_lower or not var in r_upper or var !== 32:
```

which also had a Syntax Error.

Maybe there is a way to NOT or like reverse the entire IF statement

Comment: `!==` should be `!=` instead.

Comment: If you read the SynaxError message carefully you will see the erroneous line is printed with a caret (this symbol: "^") indicating where the error is.

Comment: Why do you use ``for ...`` if you want an ``if`` statement?

Comment: Your last code was 'somehow' good, you just missed a plittle piece: `var = chr(var); if not var in r_lower or not var in r_upper or var !== 32: print 'worked'` because you have to convert the number to the equivalent character if you want to test it over a list of characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everybody is missing the point. While there are some better ways to do it, nobody is pointing the real error on your code:

Since you want the variable to be ascii letters, it **can't** be any of those conditions, so you want to use the `and` boolean operator, not `or`:

```
if var not in r_lower and var not in r_upper and var != 32:
```

That will work fine.... If you want to use `or` then the conditions change:

```
if not(var in r_lower or var in r_upper or var == 32):
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be enough:

```
import string
var = 95 ## chr(95)='_'
if chr(var) not in string.ascii_letters+' ': 
    print  'worked' ## not an alphabetic nor space character
```

EDIT:
added space to the list (ascii_letters is a string containing... letters)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the `var !== 32` it should be `var != 32:` instead.

You could simplify this like so:

```
r_upper = set(range(65, 91))
r_lower = set(range(97, 123))
r_all = r_upper.union(r_lower)
r_all.add(32)
```

And then do your check like this:

```
if var not in r_all:
```

Comment: At least make it a ``set`` instead of ``list`` to retain the O(1) test.

Answer (score 1):

Using `any()` is also a viable and good performing solution:

```
r_upper = range(65, 91)
r_lower = range(97, 123)
var = 95
if not any(var in l for l in (r_upper, r_lower, (32,))):
    print("Worked")
```

Answer (score -1):

I really don't get the for clause there as var is not an interable variable, and as everyone explained the operator is `!=` this is not javascript.

```
r_upper = range(65, 91)
r_lower = range(97, 123)
var = 95
if (var not in r_lower) or (var not in r_upper) or (var != 32):
    print("Worked")
```

If mixing up conditions its better to be explicit with the precedence on those conditions, similar to math, use parenthesis, so:

first you evaluate the Boolean value of the `not in` codition then `or` with the result of the second `not in` condition and third `or` the result of the `!=` condition

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Downvoting should stop being anonymous and have a report on the downvote.